# What is the solution to this inequality: $| 2x-3| > - | x+3|?$

Tags: functions, inequality

By using graphical method, I am getting all real numbers..
Where am I wrong in graphical method? How to solve this using calculation?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the absolute value of a number is always non-negative, the only way for this inequality to fail would be for both sides to be zero at the same time, which is clearly not possible since

- $x+3=0\implies x=-3$
- $2x-3=0\implies x=\frac32$

Your picture is fine, but usually a picture does not make a proof, it only gives a hint.

Comment: How to prove then?

Comment: What I wrote is a proof. If you are not convinced, tell me why I could add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Because absolute values are always positive we have
$$
\lvert 2x - 3 \rvert \geq 0 \geq -\lvert x + 3 \rvert
$$
for all values of $x$. Hence the only time $\lvert 2x - 3 \rvert > -\lvert x + 3 \rvert$ could potentially *not* hold is when both sides equal $0$. But $2x - 3 = 0$ if and only if $x = \frac{3}{2}$ and $x + 3 = 0$ if and only if $x = -3$ and clearly these cannot happen at the same time. Thus $\lvert 2x - 3 \rvert > -\lvert x + 3 \rvert$ holds for all values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange:
$$|2x-3|>-|x+3| \iff|2x-3|+|x+3|>0 \iff \\
|2x-3|\ne 0 \ \text{and} \ |x+3|\ne 0 \iff x\ne \frac32 \ \text{and} \ x\ne -3 \iff x\in(-\infty,+\infty).$$

Comment: “and” should be “or” ...

Comment: @MartinR, nope, it is an intersection, so "and" is right.

Comment: $|2x-3|+|x+3|$ is positive if at least one of the summands is positive, that is “or". – Also $x\ne \frac32$ **and** $x\ne -3$ would be wrong for $x=-3$.

Comment: @MartinR, the sum fails to be positive when both absolute values are zero simultaneously, so...

Comment: Sure, that would be $|2x-3|+|x+3| = 0 \iff 
|2x-3|= 0 \ \text{and} \ |x+3|=  0 $. But that is not what you say in your answer.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, I see your point. It is: $x\ne \frac32$ and $x\ne -3 \Rightarrow$ $x\in (-\infty,-3)\cup(-3,\frac32)\cup(\frac32,+\infty)$, right?

Comment: No. As I initially said, just replace “and” with “or” in your answer.

Comment: @MartinR, definitely "or" works, but I don't see why "and" does not work. Since $x$ can not equal $-3$ and $\frac32$, simultaneously (implying it is empty set), then $x$ can be any real number.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let $x \not = -3. $

The right hand side of the inequality $<0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ \ {$-3$}.

The left hand side $\ge 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ \ {$-3$}.

2)Let $x=-3:$

Right hand side = $0$, left hand side $>0$, ok.

Hence inequality is valid for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Denote $$f(x)=|2x-3|+|x+3|.$$ We want the solution for $f(x)>0$.

In fact, 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-3x，x<-3;\\
-x+6,-3 \leq x<\dfrac{3}{2};\\
3x,x \geq \dfrac{3}{2}
\end{cases}$$

[image]

Thus, all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ are the solution for $f(x)>0$.